# Как правильно отслеживать тачи в Юнити3д

Tags: unity3d, multi-touch

Я делаю игру с двумя джойстиками.
Джойстик следил за позицией тача который его тронул. Но в ситуации когда оба джойстика было тронуты и первый был отпущен, то второй джойстик имеет неверный touchId. Я попробовал отслеживать отпускание тачей подобным образом: 
Stick#1 ID0 Stick#2 ID1 (отпускаем Stick#1) Stick#2 ID1->ID0
Но в итоге получилось вот так:
(Снова трогаем Stick#1) Stick#1 ID0 Stick#2 ID0
Получается ивент система добавила новый тач уже в начало всех тачей.
Как тогда правильно отслеживать тачи?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

Вы ошибочно воспринимаете touchId, потому что не id, а index. Все касания это массив. Если элемент под индексом 0 был отпущен, то в массиве из двух тачей, второй станет единственным и будучи под индексом 1, станет под индексом 0 как единственный элемент.
В играх аналоги обычно делят на правую и левую часть экрана. Если касание началось на левой половине то под пальцем появляется левый аналог при не фиксированной позиции или проверяется попал ли ты по левому аналогу при фиксированной. Аналог становится активным и следит за ближайшим тачем проверяя все до тех пор, пока в левой стороне не останется ни одного из тачей, либо в левой половине не было события отпускания пальца. Как-то так.

Comment: Но как тогда быть если юзер будет нажимать двумя пальцами на одной половине экрана?
Меня удивляет тот факт что тачи не всегда добавляются в этот масив в конец.
При проведении теста с выводом индекса только что появившегося касания получается непонятная картина. Нажав двумя пальцами и отпустив первый, неважно сколько раз я дальше буду им касаться экрана он всегда получает индекс 0, хотя в масиве уже есть тач с таким индексом.

Comment: Если юзер будет нажимать двумя пальцами на одной половине экрана, просто сравните дистанцию отпущенного пальца и остальных, если есть палец более близкий к аналогу, то отпускание игнорируется. Ваша проблема в том, что вы фокусируетесь на конкретных индексах, а ситуация как в матрице... любой это потенциальный агент и нужно обрабатывать все тачи одновременно. Благо unity позволяет, на obj-c вы бы на стенку полезли.

Comment: И ещё про "если юзер будет нажимать двумя пальцами на одной половине экрана". Сами потыкайте на прочность ситуации в играх с аналогами и увидите, что глупости происходят, просто в 99.9(9)% случаев в лендскейп играх правый интерфес для правой руки, левый для левой и в этих глупостях нет нужды, они не провоцируются.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы обрабатываете `Touch` из списка `Input.Touches`, то каждый из них имеет свой `fingerId`, на период существования касания он остается неизменным. Анализ надо делать исходя из этого. Плюс следите за состоянием касания `Touch.phase`, отлавливайте моменты когда касание начинается и заканчивается и жить станет намного проще.